# Box doesn't capture key events in Compose Desktop

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

Keys are printed when the `TextField` is focused but not when the `Box` itself if focused.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
        println(it.key)
        false
    }.fillMaxSize().focusable()
) {
    val fieldValue = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    TextField(
        value = fieldValue.value,
        onValueChange = { fieldValue.value = it }
    )
}
```

Comment: check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68861171/3585796) on similar question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68863985/536226) answer, I change the code.

When you click on the `Box`, you remove the focus from the `TextField` but you don't give it to the `Box`. This has to be done manually.

```
val focusRequester = FocusRequester()

Box(
    modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
        println(it.key)
        false
    }.fillMaxSize()
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .focusable()
        .clickable (
            interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
            indication = null // To disable the ripple effect
        ) {
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
) {
    val fieldValue = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    TextField(
        value = fieldValue.value,
        onValueChange = { fieldValue.value = it }
    )
}
```