# onKeyEvent Modifier doesn't work in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```kotlin
return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
    setContent {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .onKeyEvent {
                    if (it.isCtrlPressed && it.key == Key.A) {
                        println("Ctrl + A is pressed")
                        true
                    } else {
                        false
                    }
                }
                .focusable()
        )
    }
}
```

Why the key event cannot be called in fragment while using hardware keyboard of tablet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As documentation of `onKeyEvent` says:

> will allow it to intercept hardware key events when it (or one of its children) is focused.

Which means you need to make your box focused, not just focusable. To do this you need a `FocusRequester`, in my example I'm asking focus when view renders. Check out more in [this article](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/focus-in-jetpack-compose-6584252257fe)

For the future note, that if user taps on a text field, your box will loose focus, but `onKeyEvent` still gonna work if this txt field is inside the box

Looks like empty box cannot become focused, so you need to add some size with a modifier. It still will be invisible:

```
val requester = remember { FocusRequester() }
Box(
    Modifier
        .onKeyEvent {
            if (it.isCtrlPressed && it.key == Key.A) {
                println("Ctrl + A is pressed")
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
        .focusRequester(requester)
        .focusable()
        .size(10.dp)
)
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    requester.requestFocus()
}
```

Alternatively just add content to `Box` so it will stretch and `.size` modifier won't be needed anymore

This code works fine with my Bluetooth keyboard + android smartphone, emulator seems not recognizing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

Comment: I used this approach to activate keyboard events within LazyVerticalGrid that contains several buttons. The only thing that ENTER key press was not handled because first control within the content was always getting focus. To avoid that I used following code:
`LaunchedEffect(Unit) { focusRequester.requestFocus() focusRequester.freeFocus() focusRequester.captureFocus() }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField` then you can use `KeyboardActions` instead:

```
keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { /* Do something */ })
```